# How to create non-clustered index for OR Operation

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, non-clustered-index, or-operator

Requirements: table `Product` has Name and Barcode

I want to create a non-clustered index to search with Name or Barcode

Query sample

```sql
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(100) = NULL

SET @Filter = '%' + ISNULL(@Filter, '') + '%'

SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE Name LIKE @Filter
OR Barcode LIKE @Filter
```

Please help me provide any the solution as separate to two indexes for name and barcode
or using one index include name and barcode

Comment: An index will not help you when your filter can start with `%`

Comment: create a FULLTEXT index and use CONTAINS() ?

Comment: Well when I say it won't help you, thats not quite true. SQL Server would still have to search every row, but with an index would read less data from the disk i.e. just the indexed columns rather than the entire row - which does improve performance a bit.

Comment: Searching by name and by barcode are logically very different search techniques. Something seems very broken if you need to search both columns using the same value. I suggest you reconsider the decisions and implementation choices that suggested this query as an appropriate path. Read this [kitchen-sink example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) for more suggestions about optimized searching - in particular the dynamic sql suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues at hand here. First off, even if an index existed on `Name` or `Barcode` your filter expression would not be able to benefit from the index (in the traditional sense for adding an index) because the expression is not sargable. Brent Ozar has a great article explaining [Why %string% Is Slow](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/)

Second, you cannot create a single index to cover filters on two separate columns where the filters on each column are independent. Meaning you are either using two separate filters (Ex: your OP), or your query only includes a filter for `Name = 'NameValue'` or vice versa. A query that has a where clause of:

```
WHERE 
    Name = 'NameValue' 
    OR 
    Barcode = 'BarcodeValue'
```

Would only be able to seek an index for both filter expressions if separate indexes existed where `Name` was the first listed column and `Barcode` was the first listed column.

An index containing two columns is meant to primarily serve the purpose of filters that use both columns as part of the filter expression. Ex: `Name = 'NameValue' AND Barcode = 'BarcodeValue'`. It is also very important to think about the ordinal position of each column within the index. For example, lets say you create this index:
`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCIX_Product_Name_Barcode ON Product (Name,Barcode);`
A query with the filter expression `Name = 'NameValue'` can still seek this index because `Name` is the first column in the index, but a query with the filter expression `Barcode = 'BarcodeValue'` cannot.

Before making any long term decisions on index design, you should first familiarize yourself with the guidelines published by Microsoft in [General Index Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#General_Design).

Lastly, if you truly need to search the `Name` or `Barcode` for string matches, you should look in to Microsoft's documentation on [full text indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15) which is likely going to be your best solution for indexed searches of this manner.